# A need to tie up cell to it's neighbor

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use spreadsheets to manage Google Ads campaigns. In first column I import campaign names using Query function:

`=QUERY('data-campaigns-all'!A:H,"select B, count(A) where A > date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE($S$1-14),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by B order by B LABEL count(A) ''")`

So I have a list of active campaigns for the day. I import other values (such as number of clicks, conversion values and so) based on campaign name, using sumifs or other formulas.

But I manually add a column with a budget for every single campaign. And it's just plain number. And when a new campaign pops up in the list, it adds a new row and whole dataset switch. All other metrics are tied up with campaign name, by some kind of formula (sumifs, vlookup and so) but budget (plain number) always stays at its place while other data shift.

[image: Sheet with shifted data]

So I want to tie up the first column (with campaign names) with budgets (which are added manually and are not in source data). The only solution that came up in my mind was to add a static sheet with campaign names and corresponding budget values and then add it to my final sheet using VLOOKUP, but I hope there's an easier solution.

Comment: `but budget always stays at its place while other data shift` Do you mean that the rest of the data shift because the new data is an inserted row rather than added at the bottom? Or do you mean that `budget` is not being recalculated on data update?

Comment: Yes - data are sorted alphabetically, so new rows are inserted randomly. It doesn't matter for most of the data in the sheet, because they are calculated based on the content of the first cell.

Like
`=sumifs('data-mfl-all'!G:G,'data-campaign-all'!$B:$B,$A2)`

But for manually added values like `2000` it's the problem because the number in cell C2 stays still the same no matter if cell A2 contains "The first campaign" or "Any other campaign".